# basic ideas of brew

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

I want to know about Binary Runtime Environment for Wireless tutorial(Brew). Any one provide some useful links to learn brew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these:

- http://www.palowireless.com/brew/tutorials.asp
- http://www.devx.com/wireless/Door/11270
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Runtime_Environment_for_Wireless

Answer (score 2):

http://brewmp.com is the marketing, non-technical site.

https://developer.brewmp.com/ is the developer portal. You may want to download the SDK and start with a primer from the Library section.

Answer (score 1):

And ofcourse you can go to:

http://brewmp.com

to download the latest SDKs and tutorials on how to actually build applications for Brew